# Is it safe to #define NULL nullptr?

Tags: c++, null, c++11, nullptr

I have seen below macro in many topmost header files:

```
#define NULL 0  // C++03
```

In all over the code, `NULL` and `0` are used interchangeably. If I change it to.

```
#define NULL nullptr  // C++11
```

Will it cause any bad side effect ? I can think of the only (good) side effect as following usage will become ill-formed;

```
int i = NULL;
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> I have seen below macro in topmost header file:

You shouldn't have seen that, the standard library defines it in `<cstddef>` (and `<stddef.h>`). And, IIRC, according to the standard, redefining names defined by standard header files results in undefined behaviour. So from a purely standardese viewpoint, you shouldn't do that.

---

I've seen people do the following, for whatever reason their broken mind thought of:

```
struct X{
  virtual void f() = NULL;
}
```

(As in [incorrectly]: "set the virtual table pointer to `NULL`")

This is only valid if `NULL` is defined as `0`, because `= 0` is the valid token for pure-virtual functions (`§9.2 [class.mem]`).

That said, **if `NULL` was *correctly* used as a null pointer constant, then nothing should break.**

However, beware that, even if seemingly used correctly, this will change:

```
void f(int){}
void f(char*){}

f(0); // calls f(int)
f(nullptr); // calls f(char*)
```

However, if that was ever the case, it was almost certainly broken anyways.

Comment: `You shouldn't have seen that`. Why you feel so ? I have even seen a strange macro like, `#define NULL (void*)(0)` in a production code for DSP for WCDMA L1.

Comment: Is `virtual void f() = 0L;` legal? Because `#define NULL 0L` certainly is a conforming implementation.

Comment: @iammilind: You shouldn't, because `NULL` is already defined by the standard.

Comment: Defining `NULL` as `(void*)(0)` is C, defining it as `0` is C++.

Comment: @Steve: IIRC, it's not. The only valid "pure-virtual-specifier" token is `=0`, but I'll look that up.

Comment: @spraff: And `nullptr` is C++.

Comment: `nullptr` is C++11, the world is still using C++03 :-)

Comment: @iammilind: because it is UB to redefine standard macros. The implementation's own header files are permitted to contain code that relies on `NULL` expanding to whatever the implementation says it expands to. In the case of `NULL` it could make a difference if the implementation (unwisely IMO, but legally) passes `NULL` as varargs parameter in a context where the function expects a pointer, secure in the knowledge that *under its calling convention*, `NULL` is the right size and will work. If you've changed it from, say, `0L` to `0` before including that header then you could break it.

Comment: @Steve: `§9.2 [class.mem]`: `pure-specifier: = 0`.

Comment: @SteveJessop, unfortunately potential UB are accepted GB (Good Behavior!) in some old implementations. I am not the one, who have done such `#define`s, but they are there as part of legacy. :)

Comment: @iammilind: sure, but having seen code with UB that works on a particular implementation (or a particular program), it's probably not a good idea to use that as evidence that you should write code with similar but different UB. It may be that defining it `0` was OK, but defining it `nullptr` was not. You just don't know until you try, and maybe not even then. So Xeo is absolutely right to say that "from a standardese viewpoint, you shouldn't do that".

Comment: Btw, if you're writing a C++11 implementation then it is legal for you to `#define NULL nullptr`, because `nullptr` is a null pointer constant, and `NULL` can be any null pointer constant. But programs aren't allowed to decide for themselves which one it should be, that's up to the implementation.

Comment: Your virtual thing is only valid if the impl defines NULL as 0. Not every implementation necessarily does that.

Comment: @Johannes: That was my point. Maybe I should change the "because" to "if", though.

Answer (score 15):

Far better is to search and replace `NULL` with `nullptr` throughout the code.

It may be syntactically safe, but where would you put the `#define`? It creates code organisation problems.

Comment: `g++ -DNULL=nullptr ...` :)

Comment: I consider code which requires certain compiler flags to be non-portable.

Comment: Well, I guess we can't -DWindows, or anything like that anymore, and we need to rewrite all our code ground up to port it to another platform...

Comment: Having an *optional* `-Dmode` switch is reasonable, assuming the code can still compile without it. Also, not every project needs to be cross-platform, but in that case, you shouldn't need to `-DWindows` or `-DAnythingElse` because it's built-in.

Answer (score 7):

No.  You're not allowed to (re)define standard macros.  And if you see

```
#define NULL 0
```

at the top of any file other than a standard header (and even there, it
should be in include guards, and typically in additional guards as
well), then that file is broken.  Remove it.

Note that good compilers will typically define `NULL` with something 
like:

```
#define NULL __builtin_null
```

, to access a compiler builtin which will trigger a warning if it is
used in a non-pointer context.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be defining it at all, unless you're writing your own version of `<cstddef>`; it certainly shouldn't be in "many topmost header files".

If you are implementing your own standard library, then the only requirement is

> 18.2/3 The macro NULL is an implementation-defined C++ null pointer constant

so either `0` or `nullptr` is acceptable, and `nullptr` is better (if your compiler supports it) for the reason you give.

Answer (score 4):

**Maybe Not**

If you have a particular format of overloading behaviour:

```
void foo(int);
void foo(char*);
```

Then the behaviour of the code:

```
foo(NULL);
```

will change depending on whether NULL is changed to nullptr or not.

Of course, there's another question as to whether it's safe to write such code as is present in this answer...

Answer (score 2):

While it might break backwards-compatibility with older stuff that was badly written *(either that, or overly clever...)*, for your newer code, this is a non-issue. You should use `nullptr`, and not `NULL`, where you mean `nullptr`. Also, you should use `0` where you mean zero.

Comment: Bear in mind that well-written older stuff won't use `nullptr` either, since it was only added to the language a few months ago.

Comment: @Mike: well-written older stuff might have something like `#define NULLPTR NULL`, though, which can be changed to `#define NULLPTR nullptr` when compiling as C++11. And then all instances of `NULLPTR` in the code removed once you're confident that you'll never again have to compile it as C++03.

Comment: @SteveJessop Seriously? I mean, maybe now that we know about nullptr that NULLPTR macro would make sense, but old code(*before* nullptr was added to the standard) having that seems.. unlikely.

Comment: @luiscabal: Bjarne Stroustrup has been advising people do so something along those lines for years. Although C++11 was only published in September, `nullptr` was in C++0x drafts for a long time before that. It wasn't a surprise!

Comment: Ah, I've just checked and I slightly misremembered. Stroustrup's C++ FAQ says to call it `nullptr`, not `NULLPTR`. Personally I wouldn't define a macro in C++03 for a symbol that I knew was due to become a keyword, that's why I said `NULLPTR` rather than `nullptr`. But it's perfectly valid provided you ensure that the macro isn't defined when building as C++11.

Comment: @SteveJessop "...I wouldn't define a macro in C++03 for a symbol that I knew was due to become a keyword..." Isn't that exactly the point of the including this particular preprocessor directive?  If you are writing it for C++03 then you don't need to include anything at all. I go with #define nullptr NULL to compile on my non C++11 compiler in the knowledge that one day I should be able to scrap the    macro altogether. In the mean time I have more readable code that is  compatible with the latest standard.