# Suppress or overwrite keyword NULL

Tags: c++, c++11

I am parsing a complex grammar which requires me to define an `enum class` like so:

```
enum class NULLSTYLE {
    NULL,
    NOTNULL
};
```

Since I could just use `0` or `nullptr` in C++11, can I somehow suppress or overwrite C++'s own definition of `NULL` so that I may stay true to my grammar?

Comment: As far as I know, `NULL` is a macro, so you probably can `#undef` it in the header right before you use it? Though http://stackoverflow.com/a/9003503/342384 reads that doing so is UB.

Comment: I recommend renaming your identifiers, such as `STYLE_NULL` and `STYLE_NOTNULL`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that is what you should do if you aren't using strongly typed enums, else it's redundant. I would recommend OP try to attempt to use something like `ISNULL` if possible.

Comment: NULL is not a keyword in either C or C++, and if uyou are parsing another 'complex grammar' it presumably isn't either of those languages in the first place. Your question  doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NULL` is not a keyword. C++11's `nullptr` is. [`NULL` is a macro.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL) If you don't directly or indirectly include any header which defines it, then in theory you can just use it for anything.

However, in practice, this is quite impossible because:

1. `NULL` is defined by many standard headers, and headers can (and generally do) indirectly include a lot of other standard headers. You will hardly want to write an enum which prevents its clients from using the standard library.
2. Using `ALL_UPPERCASE` for a non-macro identifier is usually considered bad practice anyway ([example reference](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Renum-caps)).
3. You may deal with legacy code which does not use `nullptr` but still relies on `NULL`.

You could `#undef NULL`, but that's generally a horrible hack. You could no longer write any client code which needs both your enum *and* the `NULL` macro, not to mention the fact that it would create endless confusion for everyone maintaining your code.

> ```
> enum class NULLSTYLE {
>     NULL,
>     NOTNULL
> };
> ```

This is just a case of bad naming. Make it something like this:

```
enum class NullStyle {
    Null,
    NotNull
};
```